# How to know if iPodMusicPlayer queue has been changed by another application

Tags: ios, iphone, queue, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am making a app that it is a player that plays the songs of the ipod. I also have a screen that shows the current playing list.

I know that it is impossible get the current playing queue of the ipod. So I have a screen that tell the user that I can not have access to the current playing list.

When I first enter my player, my playing list is empty and then I know, if the ipodMusicPlayer is playing, that I must present "the I do not have access screen".

But if I start to play a song with my app, after enter to Music App and change the playing list, I do not know that this change happened.

How can I know if iPodMusicPlayer queue has been changed by another application?